# Angular is giving a dropdown array in single line and how to get the select return?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array which I want to pass in a dropdown and select what user is choosing on submit and return

An HTTP Call returns this structure

```
 [
    "3/cat",
    "1/apple",
    "2/boy",
    "5/egg"
    "4/dog",
 ]
```

How it is defined..

```
//defined in a different file
    export class SchemaConfig {
        ....
        ....
        items: string[];
    }

//defined in main file
    export class ListCall implements OnInit {
      items: SchemaConfig[];
    
  ngOnInit() {
   ....
    this.getlist();
  }

 getlist() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.httpcall.getlist()
          .subscribe(
            results => {
            this.items = [];
            let items = new SchemaConfig();
            items = results;

            items.sort(function(a, b) {
              return a.localeCompare(b);
              
            });

            this.items.push(items);
            
          });
      }
}
```

This is how I define in HTML

```
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let t of items">
  {{ t }}
  </option>
  </select>
```

When this displays it comes as a long list of a single dropdown

> 1/apple,2/boy,3/cat,4/dog,5/egg

When I choose a particular array it displays it single

```
   <select>
      <option *ngFor="let t of items">
      {{ t[0] }}
      </option>
      </select>
```

> 1/apple

Questions

1. How do I get the items to be listed in a dropdown for each element separately?
2. Please let me know what all I can correct above to make it better.
3. When the item is selected I need to capture that and pass the value via a postResult() method which is doing a http call (that call is like this.httpcall.getlist() but need to pass a value back to this.httpcall.postResult(result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a stackblitz which illustrates the underlying issue with your code:](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lbrpna?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Your error is this line:

```
this.items.push(items);
```

You are pushing an array into an array:

```
this.items.push([
    "1/apple",
    "2/boy",
    "3/cat",
    "4/dog",
    "5/egg",
]);
```

Which leaves you with the structure:

```
[[
    "1/apple",
    "2/boy",
    "3/cat",
    "4/dog",
    "5/egg",
]]
```

And when this outer array is iterated over, it leaves you with a comma separated representation of the internal array.

You can, as you have discovered, access the internal array directly.

I would change your code like so:

```
getlist() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.httpcall.getlist()
          .subscribe(
            results => {
         
            results.sort(function(a, b) {
              return a.localeCompare(b);
              
            });

            this.items = results;
            
          });
      }
```

You also have a misunderstanding in how your data types work.

Your SchemaConfig class is defined as:

```
export class SchemaConfig {
  items: string[];
}
```

But you are attempting to assign an array of schemaConfigs when in fact your should have a single one with an array of items inside.

And then don't forget to add a value to your option:

```
<option *ngFor="let t of mySchemaConfig.items" [value]="t">
```

You'll then be able to use ngModel or reactive forms to post via the https service of your choice.